# Error 503 with Varnish turned off. what to do?

Tags: server, varnish

Such a problem, when updating posts (powered by Wordpress), the following message appears:

```
Error 503 first byte timeout first byte timeout. Varnish server
```

Services on the server with it do not fall, the most interesting thing is that Varnish on the server is not installed at all. Tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You may want to provide more details about your server infrastructure.

Comment: As Daniel V said, you'll need to tell a bit more about your setup. Otherwise, for reference: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#first-byte-timeout